# Service Function Not Being Triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which works fine toggling hide and show on a div element at this stage I am trying to clean up so I started using a service.

**Controller Snippet with toggle method inside**

```
    app.controller('addFormCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, Service){
      $scope.myVar = true
      $scope.toggle = function (){
        $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar
        //once toggled i.e form taken away success or failure message displayed for x time
        $scope.successOrFailureAlert = true;
        $timeout(function () {$scope.successOrFailureAlert = false}, 2000)
      }
})
```

**Service**

```
app.service('Service', function($timeout){
  var user = ""
  var location = ""

  this.toggle = function(var1,var2){
    console.log(var1)
    console.log(var2)
    var1 = !var1
    var2 = true;
    $timeout(function () {var2 = false}, 2000)
  }
})
```

**Controller with service added**

```
    app.controller('addFormCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, Service){
      $scope.myVar = true
      $scope.toggle = Service.toggle($scope.myVar, $scope.successOrFailureAlert)

      //function (){
      //  $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar
      //  once toggled i.e form taken away success or failure message displayed for x time
      //  $scope.successOrFailureAlert = true;
      //  $timeout(function () {$scope.successOrFailureAlert = false}, 2000)
      //}
})
```

When I use the service instead of defining the method there. nothing happens the toggle dosen't fire. I wish I had more to add in regards to contextual information

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="addFormCtrl">
  <span ng-show="successOrFailureAlert"> {{status}} </span>
  <button ng-click="toggle()"> Add Employee </button>
  <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submitAddEmployeeForm()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="country">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get back from the Service.toggle() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it inside a function, because your **`ng-click`** expects a function.

```
$scope.toggle = function(){
  Service.toggle($scope.myVar, $scope.successOrFailureAlert);
}
```